# Why does kworker cpu usage get so high?

Tags: 12.04, performance, cpu

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Samsung laptop alongside Windows 7. Whenever I use Ubuntu (even when its idle) kworker uses almost 90% of one of 8-cores. Even though it doesn't really affect my usage, it bugs me and I am afraid of that it might harm my processor. I even tried installing another Linux distro (Linux Mint), and kworker caused the same problem. So I don't know what to do. I would really appreciate your 
help.

[image]

Answer (score 70):

Instead I think this CPU usage is not normal and is related to the well-known kworker bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/887793

The solution for me and for many others was, first of all, find out the "gpe" that is causing the bad stuff with something like:

```
grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/
```

and check for an high value (mine was gpe13 - with a value like 200K - so, you have to change it accordingly, if differs). After that:

```
~ cp /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13 /pathtobackup
~ crontab -e
```

Add this line, so it will be executed every startup/reboot:

```
@reboot echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13
```

Save/exit. Then, to make it work also after wakeup from suspend:

```
~ touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/30_disable_gpe13
~ chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/30_disable_gpe13
~ vim /etc/pm/sleep.d/30_disable_gpe13
```

Add this stuff:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    thaw|resume)
        echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13 2>/dev/null
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

Save/exit, done.

Tested and working on :

```
Ubuntu 12.10 on Samsung Chronos 7 series - Model no. NP700Z7C --
Ubuntu 16.04.2 on Clevo - Model no. P650RS --
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: thank you!!! this is the most annoying bug I had preventing really enjoying ubuntu in my samsung.

Comment: For the benefit of future searchers, babixeddu's solution also fixed the problem on my Fedora box. My only non-zero interrupt file was grp10, and the values ranged from 7k to 15k. Although nowhere near babixeddu's 200k, the "echo disable" solution worked for my system.

Comment: Perfect! This really works on my laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS!

Comment: instead of setting the file /etc/pm/sleep.d/30_disable_gpe13 i've edited the file /etc/rc.local  and added "echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13 2>/dev/null" (before the exit 0) and now it's working, thanks

Comment: I've had this issue come up again and again for a year on my MacBook Pro. This is the first solution I have found that I could get to work. Thank you!

Comment: This also worked for me on 14.04.1 (my interrupt counts were a bit lower -- around 40k -- and the affected ones were gpe16 and gpe17).

Comment: 14.10 still has this problem (MacbookPro Retina, late 2013). Found `gpe06:94815545` and `gpe17:10621`, and after disabling the `gpe06`, kworker no longer appears at the top of the CPU ussage list, and then I could event see the power indicator *increasing* the remaining time left on battery power.

Comment: I purchased **fujitsu lifebook AH544** and I've had this issue with **ubuntu 15.10** and **ubuntu 14.04**.

My non-zero interrupt file was **/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13** .

This solution worked for my system. Thank you!

Comment: Note: I'm on Samsung Chronos 7 series - Model no. NP700Z7C running 15.10 and this is still an issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was having this issue.. Every time I opened a torrent app the CPU usage went from 0 to 100% all the time.. My first thought was that was a NTFS problem.. but no. KTORRENT was at 90% and used your guide... all works fine now :-)

Comment: The issue is still present under Ubuntu 16.04 and my solution still works well ;)

Comment: The issue affects also Debian Stretch. 3 days ago I did clean install of Debian 8.8 and immediate upgrade to Debian Stretch. Since then was looking the Net for solution. It was hard to google, because I used "one core high usage" or "process high temperature" what did not return proper solutions. I was like, owww I have to reinstall? After all that time I sacrificed for configuration and customization? I also had problems with DisplayLink adapter and the anger grow in me to the threshold I wanted to go back to old Windowz 7

Comment: One more thing, my mistake at the beginning of working out of this problem was using `htop` (freshly installed). If I used `top` I would see that `kworker` eats my CPU. Problem with `htop` is that it doesn't show `kworker` in currently running tasks!

Comment: **NOTE to others** (maybe trivial, but I'm a n00b) If `echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13`, run separately, doesn't make the kworker stop (check in another terminal with command `top` if the kworker stops) , then you probably need to run it with sudo privileges.  If that works with the individual command then use `sudo crontab -e` for the rest of the instructions, or else it doesn't work. (It didn't for me at least).

Comment: Same issue is current for Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 on Dell Inspiron 7720

Comment: This answer is a lifesaver. It's a shame to see that a **serious** 9 year old bug is still around, and apparently even affects the latest versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I had this issue after a fresh install of 18.10... I noticed issues with the brightness on my computer, booted with `nomodeset` and used the command line to download the proprietary nvidia driver. After reboot, issue resolved.

Comment: Still relevant in new machines running rolling-release distros in 2021

Comment: This is crazy that it's an issue. Pop OS 20.04

Comment: Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

The CPU usage seems to be normal, there's only 1 CPU (CPU1) that has high usage.  In all there are total 3 process that are in the running state two of them being kworker and gnome-system-mo (the first 2 processes in the top command screen short you added).

"kworker" is a placeholder process for kernel worker threads, which perform most of the actual processing for the kernel, especially in cases where there are interrupts, timers, I/O, etc. These typically correspond to the vast majority of any allocated "system" time to running processes. It is not something that can be safely removed from the system in any way, and is completely unrelated to nepomuk or KDE (except in that these programs may make system calls, which may require the kernel to do something)

For more information about kworker please have look at the following link:- [What's KWorker and it's importance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I have another question then. Is there way to make the processor use other CPUs instead of using only one core for its most of processes.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing `phc-intel` packages from [link](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa/+packages).

Comment: Not at all normal that a core is continuing to run at 80% when the system is idle.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Linux Mint 17 yesterday and noticed this evening that kworker was consuming 100% of one of 4 cpus. I ran the above check, but did not find anything other than 0 for the interrupts.

While examining the services that I normally have running, I noticed that shutting down the nfs server dropped the kworker thread back to zilch. A restart of the nfs server did not fix the issue.

I found this bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1322407), which indicates that a similar nfs server problem was fixed in kernel 3.13.0-32.57.  The latest update on Mint 17 appears to be running kernel 3.13.0-24-generic, so I don't have the fix in the kernel that I am running.  I don't know if this will help anyone else but I systematically went to each nfs client machine and did a 'umount -a -t nfs' and waited to see if it had any effect. I found the client that seemed to have been causing the issue as the kworker dropped to nothing after I unmounted. I remounted the nfs shares on the client 'mount -a -t nfs' and the problem did not return.