# Kworker consuming 100% CPU

Tags: 12.04, cpu, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kworker, what is it and why is it hogging so much CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu)

I have a process named `kworker` which is continuously consuming 100% of the CPU's computing capacity. I have tried several possible solutions over a period of 3 months but to no avail. I even got to upgrade to u + 1 (Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal), but my effort was, again, fruitless.

I desperately need some help, because, as is, this process is draining my computer's battery so fast, that makes Linux usage a disappointing experience.

It is noteworthy, that I do not have any such issues when I use windows, which results in twice as much battery life.

Comment: Some interesting links: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1630347 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2047875

Answer (score 1):

> "kworker" is a placeholder process for kernel worker threads, which
>   perform most of the actual processing for the kernel, especially in
>   cases where there are interrupts, timers, I/O, etc. These typically
>   correspond to the vast majority of any allocated "system" time to
>   running processes. It is not something that can be safely removed from
>   the system in any way, and is completely unrelated to nepomuk or KDE
>   (except in that these programs may make system calls, which may
>   require the kernel to do something).

I found this on a Ask Ubuntu question found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high). Apparently the dude's solution at that question was **I solved the problem by installing `phc-intel` packages from [link](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa/+packages)**

Some interesting information regarding what **kworker** is and its usage can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu?rq=1). Unfortunately, the solution there seems to be a future kernel upgrade.

From the same question:

> I've found many reports of something that "fixed" this for one or
>   another user. Most "fixes" seem to be related to updates of the kernel
>   of various sorts. Where the update can be tracked to a specific issue,
>   it seems to often be some driver or kernel service that has been
>   patched to not misbehave: I have the impression that there are a very
>   large number of things in the kernel that can cause a behaviour which
>   is observed as excessive kworker usage.
>
> If you find the system unusable due to excessive kworker activity, I
>   would recommend trying to do fewer things. If you think you're not
>   doing anything, try shutting down long-running services or timers (RSS
>   readers, mail readers, file indexers, activity trackers, etc.). If
>   this doesn't work, try restarting. If your system allows you to enable
>   or disable hardware in a preboot environment, try turning off hardware
>   you aren't using. If it happens on every restart before you do
>   anything, you could try uninstalling things, but at this point you'll
>   want to be running syscall profiling tools to track down specific
>   applications that seem to be causing this overload.