# 8 CPU and one is at ~100% all the time

Tags: intel, cpu, fan

With :

```
Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 3.2.0-29-generic
Intel® Core™ i7-3635QM CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8
```

The first CPU is always at ~70%-100% with nothing big running and it is making the fan noisy.
I am wondering if it is normal and if not, how can I fix this?
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Click on *Processes* tab, then View > All Processes, and click on "% CPU", what are the top processes?

Comment: gnome-system-monitor; firefox; at-spi-bus-launcher; etc
They all show 0 % CPU.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, there is kworker/0:3 in top of all. It use 72%CPU.

Comment: check what is running using the `top` command

Comment: Urgh, that is a bit complicated to figure out ... This sister site question has a relevant answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22851/why-is-kworker-consuming-so-many-resources-on-linux-3-0-0-12-server/65270#65270 to figure out the exact culprit, but the short of it is that there's likely a misbehaving driver or hardware. Unless the system is *supposed* to be doing something heavy.

Comment: Shot in the dark: `watch --interval=0.5 cat /proc/interrupts` to see if an interrupt is hammering the system.

Comment: Well, I installed Fedora 18, but I had the same issue. Sometime, CPU was at 70-100%, sometime it was normal. I followed this post : http://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high
And the first solution seems to work for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done the things described in this post : [Why does kworker cpu usage get so high?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high)
and it worked for me.