# Hundreds of "NameOwnerChanged" Dbus signals using CPU

Tags: 14.04, acpi, dbus

My laptop just ran some updates, and when prompted to restart, I did.

Now my CPU is maxing out, and my battery barely lasts 20 minutes. The processes that are going crazy are:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                          
  933 root      20   0  310236  68632   5328 S  59.4  0.9  19:13.65 polkitd                                                                                          
  520 message+  20   0   40636   3764   2256 R  31.5  0.0  10:05.80 dbus-daemon                                                                                      
  570 root      20   0   45368   5164   2856 S  21.6  0.1   6:58.41 systemd-logind                                                                                   
  904 root      20   0  345580  11164   8656 S  15.9  0.1   5:08.16 NetworkManager                                                                                   
 1423 root      20   0 2100456   8164   4980 S  13.0  0.1   4:10.18 console-kit-dae
```

This has happened once before, about a year ago, but I can't remember how I fixed it.  I do remember upvoting this [question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310196/how-can-i-figure-out-what-polkitd-is-doing-with-so-much-of-my-systems-resources/332416#332416), but the solution there doesn't work for me now (and I think I upvoted it because it was a step in the right direction, not a solution itself).

When I run `dbus-monitor --system` I see a lot of `NameOwnerChanged` events. Here's some sample output from `dbus-monitor --system "member=NameOwnerChanged"`:

```
signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> dest=(null destination) serial=376312 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.191451"
   string ""
   string ":1.191451"
signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> dest=(null destination) serial=376313 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.191452"
   string ""
   string ":1.191452"
signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> dest=(null destination) serial=376314 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.191452"
   string ":1.191452"
   string ""
```

There's about 100 NameOwnerChanged events coming through per second.

It's very frustrating. What should I try next?

Comment: Well, I ended up testing Ubuntu 16.04 on a live-USB, and it didn't have the problem, so I upgraded my whole distro.  I wish I knew the cause of the issue, but at least I can go back to using my laptop batter for more than 20 minutes...