# high CPU usage on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, performance, cpu

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Asus k53s notebook. Processor is  Intel® Core™ i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4 5.7 GiB RAM.

The CPU usage gets very high after a while, specially when using internet. It doesn't get under 70% on CPU 1, after this acceleration process starts. I've tried some thing on the terminal, but no results on that problem. Hope someone knows a good solution for this case!

Here is the information after running the `top` command:

```
top - 18:31:21 up 41 min,  2 users,  load average: 1.02, 0.93, 0.64
Tasks: 208 total,   3 running, 205 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.8%us, 20.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 77.0%id,  0.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   6019916k total,  1268444k used,  4751472k free,    31704k buffers
Swap:  4881404k total,        0k used,  4881404k free,   824920k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 R   77  0.0   8:53.81 kworker/0:0        
 1203 root      20   0  267m  48m  30m S    4  0.8   1:09.41 Xorg               
 1756 leo       20   0 1252m  78m  34m S    3  1.3   1:00.06 compiz             
 2724 leo       20   0  519m  17m  11m S    2  0.3   0:01.73 gnome-terminal     
 2789 leo       20   0 17456 1404  980 R    1  0.0   0:01.71 top                
    1 root      20   0 24596 2484 1352 S    0  0.0   0:00.95 init               
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd           
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.07 ksoftirqd/0        
    5 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
```

Thanks a lot!
Leopoldo

Answer (score 1):

The offending process is `kworker`, due to ACPI interrupts... The following resolves it:

```
sudo -i
echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe06 2>/dev/null
exit
```

Also, see [Why does kworker cpu usage get so high?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high/233947#233947) for a more complete solution.

Comment: You should split your post and ask a separate question about the shuttering issue, leaving only your solution here in the answer. That way your question will get noticed better.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some internal indexing running that's using up CPU.

I would recommend you install a different monitor called "htop". htop will give you more specific and detailed information on your processes and you'll be able to better see what process is spiking CPU for you.

To install it, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as you suggsted, I installed this program, but it doesnt really give me the reason why cpu 1 is being overcharged. the top process on the list is taking 2% of cpu, while the indicator on cpu 1 stays around 71%. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using Lubuntu (Ubuntu using lxde) instead of Ubuntu on your laptop?
Another alternate would be xfce desktop.
After all struggle with different versions of Ubuntu, I came to this solution for low CPU usage, use a distro with light desktop or just install xfce or lxde on your current distro and use that desktop instead.