# Ubuntu 14.04 - crontab @reboot hang my PC

Tags: 14.04, cron, cpu, reboot

Trying to resolving the bug for KWORKERS HIGH CPU, as suggested in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/233947/150504). I put in my crontab the row:

```
@reboot echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe06
```

After the reboot, the system doesn't start. Also in single user mode it doesn't start.

I rebooted my PC with the option:

```
init=/bin/bash
```

and I removed the row in the root crontab but the system doesn't start.

Comment: add the full path of `echo` command. $ which echo /bin/echo So : sudo crontab -e Then add the line: @reboot /bin/echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe06

Comment: Did you add that line to your crontab or to root's? What bug are you talking about? What is wrong with your system? What are the symptoms? "It doesn't start"? OK, where does it stop? Does it not even turn on? Is the screen black? Please[edit] your question and give us the information needed to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method to do a programmed reboot (although I can't think of a use case), is to create a simple script file like so:

```
(shebang)/bin/bash
sudo init 6
```

And schedule it as a normal cron job using

```
crontab -e
```

(back to the old school way)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that @reboot jobs are not run as this is a bug: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root

Answer (score -2):

Use `sudo` to run @reboot - 14.04 uses `initd` instead of `systemd` and `initd` requires root / `sudo` to reboot, while `systemd` does not.

Comment: The question isn't about how to run `reboot`.

Comment: 14.04 uses Upstart. No idea what initd is.