# Lifebook A544 Ubuntu 14.04 CPU 1 high usage

Tags: 14.04

I'm running a fairly clean install of ubuntu 14.04 64bit on my A544 laptop. I noticed however, that the fan was noisy and the battery was running down very quickly compared to windows which I run as a dual-boot. I executed top in terminal and got that the kworker/0:2 was using almost 80% of my first cpu core constantly. I did some research and I did sudo perf record -g -a sleep 10 then sudo perf report which got me the following: (http://oi57.tinypic.com/whn1ao.jpg). I have tried this post - [Why does kworker cpu usage get so high?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high) in which I found out that my gpe13 was at a very very high value of 101090676 compared to everything else being 0, 2 or 3. I typed in the cp /sys etc and then crontab -e and added the line in, restarted and still no change.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Thanks.