# Kworker shows very high CPU usage

Tags: 16.04, cpu, fan

[image]

In Ubuntu 16.04, `kworker` has a very high CPU usage. It is almost 80% all time and the fan runs at high speed and makes a loud noise. I do all commands in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high) but that wasn't useful. Now what I do?

Comment: Is any body here for answer to my question ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when installing xubuntu `16.04.3`. I reinstalled the version `16.04.2` and that solved my problem. I tried solutions like [Why does kworker cpu usage get so high?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high) but it didn't help me.