# Kworker consumes ~80% of 1 CPU core, how to get rid of this once and for all?

Tags: 16.04, cpu, cpu-load

Kworker takes about 80% of CPU1 each time I boot the system.

[image]

I tried to do as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/233947/469631). Here's the output of `grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts`:

```
root@fmcomp:~# grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci:137699572
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/error:       0
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe00:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe01:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe02:       0   enabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe03:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe04:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe05:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe06:       3   enabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe07:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe08:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe09:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe10:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe11:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe12:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13:137699366   enabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe14:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe15:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe16:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0A:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe17:     213   enabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0B:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe18:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0C:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe19:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0D:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0E:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe20:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0F:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe21:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe22:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe23:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe24:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe25:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe26:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1A:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe27:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1B:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe28:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1C:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe29:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1D:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1E:       0   enabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe30:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1F:       0   enabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe31:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe32:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe33:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe34:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe35:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe36:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2A:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe37:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2B:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe38:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2C:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe39:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2D:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2E:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2F:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3A:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3B:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3C:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3D:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3E:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3F:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci_not:      12
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_pmtimer:       0   invalid
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_rt_clk:       0   disabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe_all:137699614
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_gbl_lock:       0   enabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_pwr_btn:       0   enabled
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_slp_btn:       0   invalid
```

I edited `crontab` adding this line: `@reboot echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13` and rebooted, that didn't solve the problem.

After I type in terminal only `echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13`, CPU1 load reduces to zero and everything is OK until the next reboot or wake. [Other ways of solving this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu) don't work for me.

Are there any ways to disable gpe13 or somehow else reduce the CPU load *once and for all?*

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to `rc.local`

type `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and enter your password.

Then, above `exit 0`, add this line: `echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13` and reboot.

After logon, check that it is disabled with `cat /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13`.  If it is disabled, it will return something like `305         disabled     unmasked`.