# Htop is showing 100% cpu usage on thread 1 , on a fresh install of 17.10

Tags: cpu, htop

I have a freshly installed 17.10.1 (amd64) , my cpu : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K , and when I'm running the htop command I see that the first thread is always maxed out (98-100%), although I don't see anything using that much CPU . Is this a bug or just htop messing around ?

[image]

Comment: Do you get similar if you use `top` instead of `htop`? I also would suggest to use `turbostat` to observe what is going on.

Comment: There is clearly something going on as You have 3 running apps (1 of which is the htop itself).

Comment: Well i found out it's a process called kworker (https://imgur.com/w9jBy8X)
although it won't die when i try to kill it

Comment: No, don't try to kill it. Try to figure out what process it is associated with. (which can be difficult)

Comment: F2 > Display Options > Hide userland process threads. Try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay i found the solution in another question's answer .
Scroll down to the 2nd answer by mauro.
[Why does kworker cpu usage get so high?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high)

Everything seems to be running smoothly now. 
For me it was gpe6F
[image]