# Ubuntu 18.04 /w Macbook Pro: Kworker keeps hogging up my CPU

Tags: cpu, macbook, macbook-pro, 18.04, cpu-load

Just thought of dropping a question since this problem seems to have been around for quite some time.

Just now I have installed the new Ubuntu 18.04 on my Macbook Pro, and I notice the kworker hogging up a lot of CPU:

```
3411 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  84,4  0,0   6:12.23 kworker/0:0
```

Here's some other info about my setup:

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux MacbookPro 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Now I searched Google for answers on this problem and found plenty, actually. The answer in this thread did the trick for me: [Why does kworker cpu usage get so high?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high)

All I had to do was disable `gpe06` and the hogging kworker-process was gone. First I looked for the gpe causing the high CPU load:

```
grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/
```

Then going through the list and finding the gpe that hogs up the resources and disabling it:

```
cp /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe06 /root/gpe06.backup
echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe06
```

**My problem is that when I boot the machine, the damned kworker is running again.** I know I can just disable it each time manually, but was wondering if there's a better solution for this? I tried following the instructions on the Ask Ubuntu thread I linked above, but it seems to be an outdated guide on how to get this running on startup.

So, how do I make this a permanent solution so I don't have to disable the gpe06 each time I start the laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this : https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/7uwz3r/1604_lts_vs_1710_on_2015_macbook_pro/dto1mtb/

this following "tricks" works fine for me (same machine, same problem, same gpe) :

```
sudo -s
crontab -e
```

and add this following line at the end :

```
@reboot echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe06
```

Comment: Nice one, this sorted it out, thanks!

Note to self: Learn to read manuals... :D

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running Lubuntu 20.10, 5.8 kernel, in an old Macbook 2006.
In my case the solution was to mask gpe17 using boot parameter

I added boot parameter `acpi_mask_gpe=0x17` to GRUB and rebooted.

Add `acpi_mask_gpe=0x17` to `/etc/default/grub` line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, then run `update-grub` and reboot.

That solved the high CPU utilization.

I found the problem with this command:
`grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/`

The issue:
`/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe17: 3491042 EN enabled unmasked`

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I'm enjoying the silence. No fan, no cpu madness,