# CPU Core Stuck at 100% due to kworker (alx)

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, cpu

On startup, one of my CPU would become maxed out at 100% load. Upon looking `pref` the `kworker` is busy with something called `alx_`. alx appears to be related to the network card `Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller`.

With one CPU stuck at 100%, I cannot use the laptop, because at best keyboard cooks my hand slowly at 70C+. A possible solution posted was to disable `kworker` directly, which isn't ideal (see [CPU Core Stuck at 100%](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029745/ubuntu-18-04-w-macbook-pro-kworker-keeps-hogging-up-my-cpu-solved)). If possible, I would like to fix the problem that causes the spike in `kworker` load.

Comment: Version is `1.173.1`. I tried the `gpe` solution, but there is no obvious culprit. They mention that there should be a high `gpe` value, but mine are all sub 100.

Comment: I installed the latest firmware and kernal, but the problem persists when I comment off the `crontab` edits. I am rather confused about what exactly is causing the gpe. When I disable `gpe06` the issues goes away. I think `17` might also be an issue. Additionally, it can take a bit before this issue is triggered. For `06`, I assume I have to access wifi.