# High kworker CPU usage on Ubuntu 18.04 (tried multiple things with no results)

Tags: cpu

A fresh 18.04 Ubuntu install on a Windows Surface Book 2 dual-booting Windows 10. The `kworker/0:0+kac` process never goes below 80% CPU.

[image]

I tried this [Why does kworker cpu usage get so high?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high) but I don't have any interrupts above 10, and when I disabled those ones it fixed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Surface devices need a custom kernel to work with Linux (includes Battery Indicator, Touch, Pen, etc. ). Following the guide at https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface fixed the problem for me.