# kworker eating 85% CPU 1 most of the time!

Tags: 18.04, performance, cpu-load

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 5.4.81, and `kworker/0:1+kac` is using 85% CPU 1 most of the time.

Here is some useful info:

- `top` output:

  [image: top cmd]
- System Monitor CPU load:

  [image: CPU load pic]
- `perf` report:

  ```
  Samples: 56K of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 29364654484
    Children      Self  Command          Shared Object                 Symbol
  +   80.07%     0.00%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] ret_from_fork
  +   80.07%     0.00%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] kthread
  +   80.07%     0.00%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] worker_thread
  +   79.96%     0.03%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] process_one_work
  +   79.93%     0.00%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_os_execute_deferred
  +   78.59%     0.01%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ev_asynch_execute_gpe_m
  +   78.54%     0.01%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ns_evaluate
  +   78.25%     0.01%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ps_execute_method
  +   78.10%     0.03%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ps_parse_aml
  +   75.07%     0.71%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ps_parse_loop
  +   49.25%     0.52%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ds_exec_end_op
  +   27.27%     0.25%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ns_lookup
  +   26.93%     0.19%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ns_search_and_enter
  +   26.48%    26.16%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ns_search_one_scope
  +   26.00%     0.05%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ds_evaluate_name_path
  +   19.60%     3.27%  kworker/0:1-kac  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] acpi_ut_update_object_refere
  +   17.80%     0.00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] secondary_startup_64
  +   17.80%     0.00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] cpu_startup_entry
  +   17.78%     0.03%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] do_idle
  +   17.29%     0.01%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] call_cpuidle
  +   17.28%     0.00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] cpuidle_enter
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I was helped taming such `kworker` runaway processes by disabling an interrupt, inspired [by this thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/high-cpu-usage-by-kworker-4175563563/) and [an old answer by Mauro Mascia](https://askubuntu.com/a/233947/558158) anwered, burried on this site because it has unfortunately been marked as a "Duplicate" to another question, that did not provide a solution. Therefore, users will not easily find it.

The Ubuntu bug report on this issue (not solved) is [887793](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/887793). It also contains a suggestion to workaround the issue:

```
echo N > /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
```

I used the approach described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/233947/558158). It is somewhat complicated because it involves finding out the interrupt(s) that cause the issue. I have a single line in the form of

```
echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/#####
```

(with `#####` denoting the interrupt number, which will be different between computers) in the crontab of root.

I did not test the first approach, and I do not know which of both approaches is impacting system performance the least (if at all noticeable - and in many case by far preferred over a runaway kworker process).