# Kernel worker uses one core at 80% all the time

Tags: kernel, updates

I'm having a problem with kernel using much cpu on latest ubuntu 21.10.

[one core is used at 80%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Raeul.png)

[the kworker uses actually 10% of CPU which is 80% on one core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e18WP.png)

I've tried to do this workaround:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/high-cpu-usage-by-kworker-4175563563/
but matter what I did, I can't modify the dirty_writeback_centisecs file.
Sometimes after some "Main components update" or GPU driver update problem goes away, but then it returns, and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: A bug as old as the street, not frequently reported because many users find it normal that the fan is on all the time. The accepted answer in the thread I referred to helped me. It is rather complicated, though: you have to identify and disable interrupts that cause the problem. For me, it was enough to disable gpe13. I have this in effect since 2019 - would need to test if it is still needed in Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: So I've just tried these solutuions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high but it says no permision when i try to disable interrurpt which has high number I get permision denied.

Comment: How did you disable them? Because for me even using sudo won't let it disable. I'm wondering if disabling whole ACPI would help..

Comment: I just followed the instructions. I live with a line in my crontab, and with a `/etc/pm/sleep.d/30_disable_gpe6F` file that executes the same command after sleep or hibernate. Still from 19.10: against better advise, I have been upgrading since then rather than installing anew.

Comment: Seems like it says no permission, but now CPU usage loks good.

Comment: I cannot see where it could say that, but anyway, keep a watch. If not solved, the problem will reappear any time sooner or later after rebooting.

Comment: Yes you were right, usage seems to go away while working on battery. I had to reinstall ubuntu yesterday and now it's ok.

Comment: I have also noticed that reconnecting external display removes the problem for some time.