# kworker hogging the processor issue

Tags: 22.04, laptop

I'm experiencing the "kworker hogging 100% of my CPU" issue.  It cropped up a few months ago, and I did something, probably found right here, and fixed it.  I wish I could remember what it was.  Anyway, I rebooted my laptop last night, and the problem recurred.  Top shows that for about 40 seconds of every minute, kworker pushes my processor to 100%, and everything just stops, the mouse pointer vanishes, the keystrokes go into a buffer, and appear when the processor is freed.  I'm working through the suggestions in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high/233947#233947) post and the author states that they ran:

`grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/`

And that yielded the information that one of their interrupts had a value of 200k, so that was clearly their problem.  When I run it, my results show that the highest value any of my interrupts are set to is 19.  I have not much of an idea what any of this means, but 19 doesn't seem very high when the other guy saw 200k.  I'm not sure where to go from here.

Since someone will probably ask, I'm running a ROG Strix G17, and :

`cat /etc/os-release`

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Thanks in advance for any help that can be offered.

Charlie Bravo

Comment: can you tame it with "sudo renice -n 20 $(pidof kworker)"

Comment: I got this as a reply, which may mean it's working:

    (hostname)~$ 180 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority 19
After running top, I am seeing lines like this, with percentages as high as 65%
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                              
  6180 root      20   0       0      0      0 I                 16.9   0.0         384:00.25 kworker/3:2-events

Comment: renice does not guarantee low cpu usage, just nicer to other processes that might be hogged. a few here you can look up   https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3Akworker

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/659164/kworker-consuming-90-io-and-zero-disk-write/785415#785415

Comment: sudo lsof | grep kworker 

to see if writing to a drive and which files?