# How do I modify "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"

Tags: 16.04, kernel, systemd, mongodb, sysfs

I use mongodb 3.0 and I find a warning:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.0
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2015-03-13T16:28:29.405+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-03-13T16:28:29.406+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2015-03-13T16:28:29.406+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-03-13T16:28:29.406+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-03-13T16:28:29.407+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-03-13T16:28:29.407+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-03-13T16:28:29.407+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

---

```
~# cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
[always] madvise never

~# cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
[always] madvise never
```

I try to use echo, but it's not permanent, after reboot it will be reset.

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

How do I modify `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` permanently?

Comment: There may be good answers below, but IMO you should have a look at the official documentation of MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can

1. install the `sysfsutils` package:

   ```
   sudo apt install sysfsutils
   ```
2. and append a line with that setting to `/etc/sysfs.conf`:

   ```
   kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled = never
   ```

This is the cleanest solution, because it keeps all the sysfs configuration in one place instead of relying on custom start-up scripts. The other answers, with the scripts and conditional expressions, are suitable if you don't know through which path the kernel will expose that setting, i. e. if you don't even have a rough idea of the kernel version running on the affected machine.

Comment: This did nothing for me on Ubuntu 14.04 on an AWS EC2 instance.  I don't know much about sysfs.conf but it does seem to be an Ubuntu supported configuration, yet the file didn't exist on our system previously, and adding it and rebooting didn't change the mongo output warnings at all.  Also tried clayzermk1's advice below, 'defrag' warning still appeared.  The official mongo docs init script did remove both warnings.

Comment: What's the output of `cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`? Does it exist at all? `sysfs.conf` is normally evaluated at boot by `/etc/init.d/sysutils`. Is it enabled? What happens, when you invoke `/etc/init.d/sysutils start`?

Comment: `$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
    [always] madvise never
    $ ls -l /etc/sysfs.conf
    ls: cannot access /etc/sysfs.conf: No such file or directory
    $ ls -l /etc/init.d/sysutils
    ls: cannot access /etc/init.d/sysutils: No such file or directory`
It seems these AWS EC2 Ubuntu instances don't come with sysutils installed at all.  Since the recommended Mongo docs did fix my problem, I'm hesitant to install sysutils and mess with the EC2 instance when I'm not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: I'm not surprised at the different system configuration of EC2. That's exactly why they're off topic here.

Comment: I also don't have `sysfs.conf` file and `/etc/init.d/sysutils`. ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Shouldn't this be `/etc/sysctl.conf`?

Comment: @unhammer: No, the two have a different scopes. `sysctl` is for settings that you could also achieve with kernel parameters; `sysfs.conf` is for entries in `/sys`.

Comment: @HEX On Ubuntu 16.04 systemd is used, thus after changing `/etc/sysfs.conf` sysfsutils service has to be restarted using `systemctl restart sysfsutils.service` ... did the job for me here.

Comment: @cepharum: Yes, `sysfs.conf` is read by a service (usually upon boot). That is true for other versions of Ubuntu too.

Comment: @DavidFoerster My comment was somewhat ambiguous indeed as I was basically referring to reason for missing `/etc/init.d/sysutils` in Ubuntu 16.04 and later ...

Comment: This doesn't solve the `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag` warning

Comment: @orszaczky: That wasn't the question as far as I understand it. You're welcome to [open a new question](/questions/ask) about that. :-)

Comment: After following the answer, I still need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` followed by `systemctl restart mongodb` to get rid of the error (on Ubuntu 17.04)

Comment: @YohanesGultom: Obviously the setting can only apply to newly created processes. This only applies when the setting was modified *at runtime*, i. e. not at boot time, which means it outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: For me, it seems the redis-server is started before this setting change. If I look at the shell `cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` or restart redis, everything seems ok. Any thoughts?

Comment: @navossoc: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: I have found this to be the easiest way in Ubuntu 18.04 and cleanest solution to persist disabling THP

Answer (score 26):

The MongoDB docs have a few suggestions. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/transparent-huge-pages/

The "preferred" way is to edit `/etc/default/grub` and append `transparent_hugepage=never` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` then run `update-grub` to rebuild the GRUB configuration.

The following two-liner will do just that. Make sure to verify the output!

```
sed -r 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="[a-zA-Z0-9_= ]*/& transparent_hugepage=never/' /etc/default/grub | sudo tee /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

Note that `update-grub` is a wrapper for `grub-mkconfig`. `grub-mkconfig` will clobber entries in `/etc/default/grub` with those from `/etc/default/grub.d/*`.
If by chance you are running on AWS, you will need to instead edit `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg`.

The "alternate" method is to edit `/etc/rc.local` and add the following before `exit 0`:

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/khugepaged/defrag; then
  echo 0 > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/khugepaged/defrag
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
  echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
  echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
```

Personally, I ended up doing both the "preferred" and "alternate" methods since they aren't mutually exclusive and it eliminates the warning about defrag.

* Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04, MongoDB 3.0.2, and AWS.

Comment: I tried this at my one-click MongoDB application server on DigitalOcean and it didn't work. Still getting the same warning message.

Comment: Thank you for the part about EC2 and `50-cloudimg-settings.cfg`

Answer (score 17):

Here's a solution that has been tested to work on Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS EC2. Ubuntu 16.04 uses the systemd init system, and this config file expresses that these settings should be changed before MongoDB boots up.

Create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/mongodb-hugepage-fix.service` and add the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description="Disable Transparent Hugepage before MongoDB boots"
#WARN: check service name on your system
# If you are using MongoDB Cloud, service name is "mongodb-mms-automation-agent.service"
Before=mongodb.service      

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag'

[Install]
#WARN: check service name on your system
# If you are using MongoDB Cloud, service name is "mongodb-mms-automation-agent.service"
RequiredBy=mongodb.service
```

To load the file into systemd:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

To activate the file as a boot-time dependency of MongoDB

```
systemctl enable mongodb-hugepage-fix
```

If you want to activate the changes immediately (before the next boot)

```
systemctl start mongodb-hugepage-fix
systemctl restart mongod
```

This solution is *not* suitable for Ubuntu 14.04, which uses the Upstart init solution instead of systemd.

Comment: The systemd fix is perfect for modern MongoDB installs, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Append the following lines below into of /etc/rc.local.

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
  echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi

if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
```

This will run when you reboot the server.

Comment: Is there a config file about this? ``rc.local`` is not a good idea, because rc.local will execute at the end of system start up. So mongodb service will still use the default setting.

Comment: edit the /etc/default/grub file and make changes to the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="transparent_hugepage=never"  and run the update-grub command then restart the server

Comment: Thanks, it works. But, is there a similar way to modify ``/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag``? When I reboot, mongo shell also tells me "** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'."

Comment: @FengYu try this page https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/

Answer (score 1):

Since we are deploying machines with Ansible I don't like modifying rc files.

I tried using `sysfsutils` / `sysfs.conf` but ran into timing issues when starting the services on fast (or slow machines). It looked like sometimes mongod was started before sysfsutils. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it did not.

Since mongod is an upstart process I found that the cleanest solution was to add the file `/etc/mongo_vm_settings.conf` with the following content:

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongod_vm_settings.conf
#
#   This file will set the correct kernel VM settings for MongoDB
#   This file is maintained in Ansible

start on (starting mongod)
script
  echo "never" > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
  echo "never" > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
end script
```

This will run the script just before mongod will be started.
Restart mongod (`sudo service mongod restart`) and done.

Comment: Note that this solution uses the "Upstart" init system, while Ubuntu 16.04 is based on the systemd init system.

Answer (score 1):

After reading a little bit in the warning log I've added these two lines in `/etc/sysfs.conf` y voilá

```
kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled = never
kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag = never
```

Reboot the machine after applying these changes.

Comment: That still requires the `sysfsutils` package (see my answer).

Comment: surely it is needed

Answer (score 0):

GRUB will change after upgrade, and rc.local will run only after mongo is started, so maybe we should add service mongo restart  at the end of rc.local like this

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
  echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi

if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi

wait 1 && servie mongod restart
```

or maybe someone successfully added the lines above to init script in Ubuntu 14.04?