# Can I use 14.04 MongoDB Packages with 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

Unfortunately the official Ubuntu package for MongoDB is still stuck on 2.6, which is ancient at this point ([this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mongodb/+bug/1428749) didn't get picked up for vivid, wily or xenial).

MongoDB has not yet released a package for 16.04 (Xenial), so how can I use the 14.04 (Trusty) packages to install MongoDB 3.2+ on 16.04?

Comment: Yes you can. If you're upgrading, it should be easy. If you fresh installed 16.04, simply follow the steps here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/724749/install-mongo-3-2-on-ubuntu-15-10/724788#724788

Comment: @Rexford As you'll see in the answer below it's not quite that easy in 16.04 with the old packages (the service won't get installed properly with a fresh install)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack but yes, this can be done. There is an undocumented step needed to actually start the service and (weirdly enough) unless you want to futz around with upstart job conversion manually, you need to install the Ubuntu `mongodb` package first, then remove it so that you have a usable service.  A straight install of the MongoDB packages **will not give you a working service** on a fresh 16.04.

**Update - July 2016:** The official fix for this (adding support for 16.04 to the packages) has been completed in the 3.3 dev branch as part of [SERVER-23043](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23043) - and has been released as a backport in the 3.2 series as [part of 3.2.7](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-announce/jU8rzxo_Mc8).  Hence, if you are using 3.2.7+ you do **not** need to do this and the official MongoDB package install should just work.

In any case, after doing the add/remove, follow [the usual instructions](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#import-the-public-key-used-by-the-package-management-system) for 14.04, summarized here:

```
# install the Ubuntu package (to get the service set up correctly)
sudo apt-get install mongodb
# Now remove it and continue with the MongoDB instructions
sudo apt-get remove mongodb
sudo apt-get autoremove
# import key
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
# add trusty repos
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
# update apt
sudo apt-get update
# install the MongoDB package
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

The install succeeds, and thanks to the Ubuntu package we have all the pieces needed for a service, but attempting to start the service will initially fail:

```
$ sudo service mongodb start
Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is masked.
```

Fixing this is not too hard:

```
$ sudo systemctl unmask mongodb
Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service.
```

Now we can enable/start the service, get its status etc.

```
$ sudo service mongodb enable
$ sudo service mongodb start
$ sudo service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - LSB: An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mongodb; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-04-14 16:40:35 IST; 7s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2849 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mongodb start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1593 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 13 (limit: 512)
   Memory: 51.9M
      CPU: 100ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
           └─2861 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Success - and we get a nice pointer to the active config file (which is in the old `key=value` format, see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82592/6441) for examples in the newer recommended YAML format).

**Note:** There will actually be two config files `/etc/mongod.conf` and `/etc/mongodb.conf` thanks to slight differences between the two packages we have installed.  The now-active service points to the old-format one by default `/etc/mongodb.conf` - you can switch by moving/copying the `mongod.conf` to `mongodb.conf` if you so wish, or simply edit the file directly.

Once started, to test, connect to the database with the `mongo` shell:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-04-14T16:40:34.962+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

If you wish to get rid of the THP warnings, check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/610707/130555).

Comment: After your first block of code above, running `sudo service mongodb start` returns `Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service not found`.

Comment: I tried to resolve the above by creating a service file for systemd (as per http://askubuntu.com/a/694226/367134). This is the result: `sudo service mongodb start` returns nothing. `sudo service mongodb status` returns a failed message with `status=2`. To fix this, I changed path in newly created service file from `/etc/mongodb.conf` to `/etc/mongod.conf`.  Building on your original answer, how do you get mongodb to start on system start up?

Comment: The following additional action enabled mongodb to start on system startup for me:  `sudo systemctl enable mongodb`.   See:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Comment: Ah, pretty sure I just left that line out when copy/pasting my instructions, or I would have failed similarly, thanks for the heads up

Comment: also regarding the config files, seems I have both config files in `/etc` (likely left over from the prior installation of the Ubuntu package and subsequent removal).  I will re-work the answer to cover this, basically a clean and unclean version of the same thing

Comment: I wrote up my process here, referencing your answer and outlining some steps I took to clean up old installations, might be of interest:  http://askubuntu.com/a/759816/367134

Comment: I get `E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org`. I only have `mongodb`, `mongodb-clients` and `mongodb-server` available...

Comment: Which isn't that surprising, now that I'm looking at it... their i386 "Packages" file is empty... Only 64-bit support, then?

Comment: Yep, that's the case, 32-bit is deprecated generally (and has been limited for many years) and will be removed completely post-3.2, plus the Ubuntu install page explicitly says: "MongoDB only provides packages for 64-bit long-term support Ubuntu releases" (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: It appears that problem is not fixed still.
`$ mongod --version`

`db version v3.2.8`
`git version: ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0`
`OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016`
`allocator: tcmalloc`
`modules: none`
`build environment:`
`distmod: ubuntu1604`
`distarch: x86_64`
`target_arch: x86_64`
`$ sudo service mongodb start`
`Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service not found.`

Comment: Definitely not fixed in 3.2.8. See [the last comment](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24539?focusedCommentId=1325328&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1325328). Should be tackled in 3.2.9.

Comment: currently traveling, once I get back I will actually test the packages to make sure they work - thanks @GoranMiskovic

Answer (score -1):

If you have already installed it, remove mongodb by:

```
sudo apt-get remove mongodb
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Try with recommendation on digitalocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: While your answer may be valid, it would be better to provide the steps listed in your link here. Links and their content can change over time which would render your answer useless.