# Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS and MongoDB not working

Tags: server, mongodb

I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS and have been having trouble for the past 5 days. One of the problems is this after input this command: `mongo`

```
Server has startup warnings:
2016-12-19T08:40:14.039-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-12-19T08:40:15.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

I am new to Ubuntu and hoping for a step by step solution

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues to handle:

1. You haven't configured the *security features* in your *mongodb*:

   - Follow the official steps to doing so [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-security-part-ii-10-mistakes-that-can)
2. Disable Transparent Huge Pages (THP):

   - there are two options [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597372/how-do-i-modify-sys-kernel-mm-transparent-hugepage-enabled), look at the second answer but if the accepted answer works for you fine:

     - adding the following to the `/etc/rc.local` file before the *exit 0*

       ```
       if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/khugepaged/defrag; then
       echo 0 > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/khugepaged/defrag
       fi
       if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
         echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
       fi
       if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
         echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
       fi
       ```
     - edit `/etc/default/grub`:

       - append `transparent_hugepage=never` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` then
       - run `update-grub`

Sources:

[How do I modify "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597372/how-do-i-modify-sys-kernel-mm-transparent-hugepage-enabled)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/#transparent-huge-pages-thp-settings

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-security-part-ii-10-mistakes-that-can

Comment: Thank you very much. I am looking at the video for the past few days. Will be done soon and come back with the update.