# how do I make "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag" never status to close the THP warning

Tags: kernel, systemd, defrag, redis, sysfs

reboot the linux (ubuntu 16.04 redis 4.011)

```
/var/log/redis.log
```

shows

```
# WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
```

So I do

way1:

```
/etc/rc.local

if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
```

when reboot the machine

```
the /var/log/redis.log shows the THP warning still.
```

But when I use

```
$cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
$cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
always defer madvise [never]
```

I got the right [never]

```
$systemctl restart redis

the /var/log/redis.log shows no THP warning.
```

But it is not correct the issue as when the machine reboot is still having the THP warning.

So I try
way2:
remove the /etc/rc.local if...fi sentence first

```
$apt install sysfsutils
```

add these two lines to /etc/sysfs.conf:

```
kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled = never  
kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag = never
```

reboot

```
/var/log/redis.log got no any new message???
```

how can I get my log again? Is the sysfutils eat it?

```
$systemctl status redis
```

the redis is active.

```
$cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
$cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
always defer [madvise] never
```

I got [madvise] ?????

then

```
$systemctl restart redis
$cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
$cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
always defer [madvise] never
```

the [madvise] come again?
the[never] for the defrag  is not choose right??!

it's strage when I change the enabled and defrag on /etc/sysfs.conf:

```
kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag = never   
kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled = never
```

I got the right cat result
    $systemctl restart redis
    $cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
    always madvise [never]
    $cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
    always defer madvise [never]

But still no any message added to my /var/log/redis.log when reboot the linux.

But can add new message when I command "systemctl restart redis"

why is so strange situation? which is correct and how to fix it?

Comment: See this answer to a similar question: https://askubuntu.com/a/610707/917104

Answer (score 1):

So as you I had this question and I went to github and forum to find the answer, and actually it result from a mix of a little bit all of them

I think you were on the good way but the main mistake everybody seams to do is to not restart the redis service after applying the new THP rules.

### 1. add rc.local

So first, on ubuntu 20.04 by default the rc.local don't exist, which I fixed by following those step ([ref](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd))

> as root

#### 1.1. make a systemd service for rc-local

add in /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service

```
[Unit]  
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility  
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local  

[Service]  
 Type=forking  
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start  
 TimeoutSec=0  
 StandardOutput=tty  
 RemainAfterExit=yes  
 SysVStartPriority=99  

[Install]  
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### 1.2. active it

```
touch /etc/rc.local  
chmod +x /etc/rc.local  
systemctl enable rc-local
```

1.2.1 in that file (rc.local) you could add

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled  
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag  
systemctl restart redis-server.service  
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler to use systemd-tmpfiles:

```
# cat /etc/tmpfiles.d/disable-thp.conf
#Type Path                                                  Mode UID GID  Age Argument
w     /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled           -    -   -    -   never
w     /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag            -    -   -    -   never

# systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix=/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/ /etc/tmpfiles.d/disable-thp.conf

# grep -E . /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag:always defer defer+madvise madvise [never]
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled:always madvise [never]
```

Of course, there's no need to always run `systemd-tmpfiles` manually, it'll be run by the `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` on boot.