# KswapD0 use 100% CPU

Tags: cpu, 16.04, overheating

After upgrde from 15.10 to 16.04, I noticed my netbook fan was constantly turning at full throtle.
I checked the process mnitoor and noticed KswapD0 used 100% of one core.

What is the problem ?
Because of this, my netbook is slow and i'm afraid of processor overheating.

Comment: That certainly does sound like a bug you should report, but even if all cores are running at 100%, it should not overheat.  If it does, your hardware is defective.

Comment: This happened to me on a AWS instance with low memory as folks in the link provided above in regards to BUG #1518457, after I updated from a 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS with a do -release-upgrade. Refer to the discussion thread for more detail. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1518457

Answer (score 21):

This seems to be something that commonly (but not exclusively) pops up w/ low memory systems. You can check out the bug that's tracking this issue: [Bug #1518457: kswapd0 100% CPU usage](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1518457)

There isn't an actual fix yet, but there are a couple workarounds that may fix the problem for you:

1. Add `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to a regular crontab and/or run that command manually when kswapd acts up
2. Comment out line 2 in `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-vm-hotadd.rules` (see the bug link for more discussion)

Comment: *1.* Drops clean page caches. It is non-destructive, but can cause performance problems.

Comment: *2.* You should quote the line to be removed in case they change the order of the lines in the future.

Comment: true, it's actually line 3 now (considering the first line is a comment)

`ATTR{[dmi/id]sys_vendor}=="Xen", GOTO="vm_hotadd_apply"`

Comment: do I need to sudo first? and how do I sudo for the cronjob

Comment: The fix has been released for 16.04 and has been confirmed fixed by multiple people.  Run apt-get upgrade and restart.

Comment: [This problem "never solved"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072042), is it? So, today, 2017, there are a workwaround to avoid crashing UBUNTU with kswapd0 consuming all my CPY time?

Comment: See another solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/530661/439867