# WordPress high Steal time on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, apache2, swap, amazon-ec2, wordpress

I am having a dynamic wordpress website with multiple plugins, installed over an AWS EC2 t2.micro Instance with an ubuntu 16.04.

At some point of working on the admin panel on different occasions, the website becomes extremely slow. I Installed netdata [here](http://cosyclassics.cz:50000/) for an easier way of monitoring the CPU performance. It seems that the steal time out is eating up the CPU even if I stopped working on the website completely. When I checked `top` command to track the processes, I found out that Kswapd0 is taking from 95% - 100% of the CPU, Check here: [Performance Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEu27.png).

When I searched the issue and followed the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259739/kswapd0-is-taking-a-lot-of-cpu) to make sure that the swap only starts being used when there is 0% left memory using the following command : `echo vm.swappiness=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf`nothing changed.

I read that it might be because I am using a micro instance and multiple people are facing this issue as well, I do not mind increasing the instance if this is the issue and pay for a small or medium instance but I just need to make sure of that before launching the website.

Any help on this? I am new to this so please let me know if there is supposed to be any further information in order to be able to find a solution.

Edit: I just tailed the the access.log and found out the following:`41.130.43.196 - - [30/Sep/2016:20:27:31 +0200] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HT                                                                                                             TP/1.1" 200 475 "http://cosyclassics.cz/wp-admin/post.php?lang=en&action=edit&po                                                                                                             st_type=page&post=5465" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/5                                                                                                             37.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36"`  that repeats every couple of minutes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the bug at [kswapd0 100% CPU usage (Ubuntu Bugs)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1518457)

The workaround is to run this command:

```
sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/40-vm-hotadd.rules
```