# kswapd0 taking 100% CPU time on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kernel, cpu

My Dell Latitude E7390(16 GB Memory, Intel i5 8th Generation Octa Core), running Ubuntu 18.04 has been facing this issue a lot where this process `kswapd0` takes ~100% of CPU time on one or more cores.

I have to go to tty and kill that process(which respawns since it's a root process)

Attached image of `top` results for one of such instances:
[image: <code>top</code> in TTY]

I have found many similar questions detailing this issue, however, most of these are old and some claim that this was a Linux kernel bug that was fixed for Ubuntu in 16.04. Also, all the answers are about 2-3 years old on different hardware and software models. Hence, re-asking this question here for these newer models.
Similar questions ( Most of these are workarounds) :

[kswapd0 is taking a lot of cpu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259739/kswapd0-is-taking-a-lot-of-cpu)

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/kswapd0-at-100-cpu-4175585351/

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65201

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1518457

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=205654 (This is one for arch, but still relevant)

P.S.: Screenshot of `uname -a` for my system for reference

[image]

Comment: The 'Shellbot' miner malware disguises itself as kswapd0, check the user's most recent created files

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem recently, and I found that kswapd0 in my case is actually a crypto miner. (Please refer to this post: https://yoroi.company/research/outlaw-is-back-a-new-crypto-botnet-targets-european-organizations/)

You can check your files to see if there is a folder called `.rsync` (or `.configrc` in my case). Usually you will find the program `kswapd0` under the folder `a/`.

If you find that suspicious folder, then with high probability your server is infected.

Comment: in deed I find all the signs of the crypto-botnet infection. I have fortified the login with ssh keys. I also removed the user id related to the infection, but the high cpu persists. Anyone knows how to remove it?