# Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS freezes completely and logs point to mouse curser problems

Tags: xubuntu, thinkpad, ubuntu-gnome

In the last two weeks my system froze two or three times, when I had a few browser windows and MS Teams open at the same time, but nothing it couldn't handle before.

The resource monitor points to maxed out RAM, but CPU is also maxed out at around 95% but fluctuating.

By freeze I mean all screens freeze and the mouse curser too. It freezes for like a split second and everything lags for like one second and then it goes to the full on freeze. I also don't hear any sound anymore. At this point I cannot open terminal anymore and no keypress seems to do anything, the only thing I can do at this point is `ALT`+`PRINT`+`REISUB` for reboot.

I used `journalctl -b -1 -e` to show the logs of the previous boot, and all I can understand from it is there are some errors pointing towards problems with my mousepad lag, and when I search for these errors online, I just find answers like I should ignore them and they aren't harmful at all.

Here are the complete logs:

```
Mär 07 09:31:10 lin-messnere msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[4417]: [21110:26:0307/093110.423372:ERROR:sdp_offer_answer.cc(396)] A BUNDLE group contains a codec collision for payload_typ>
Mär 07 09:31:15 lin-messnere msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[4417]: [21110:26:0307/093115.500311:ERROR:sdp_offer_answer.cc(396)] A BUNDLE group contains a codec collision for payload_typ>
Mär 07 09:32:50 lin-messnere msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[4417]: [21110:26:0307/093250.907741:ERROR:sdp_offer_answer.cc(396)] A BUNDLE group contains a codec collision for payload_typ>
Mär 07 09:32:51 lin-messnere msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[4417]: [21110:26:0307/093251.119272:ERROR:sdp_offer_answer.cc(396)] A BUNDLE group contains a codec collision for payload_typ>
Mär 07 09:32:55 lin-messnere msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[4417]: [4411:4411:0307/093255.054458:ERROR:atom_cache.cc(230)] Add chromium/from-privileged to kAtomsToCache
Mär 07 09:34:17 lin-messnere systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Mär 07 09:34:18 lin-messnere systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mär 07 09:34:18 lin-messnere anacron[21702]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2024-03-07
Mär 07 09:34:18 lin-messnere anacron[21702]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Mär 07 09:35:16 lin-messnere msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[4417]: [4411:4411:0307/093516.890535:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(707)] Message 3 rejected by interface blink.mojom.Wid>
Mär 07 09:35:21 lin-messnere msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[4417]: [21110:26:0307/093521.189579:ERROR:sdp_offer_answer.cc(396)] A BUNDLE group contains a codec collision for payload_typ>
Mär 07 09:35:35 lin-messnere msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[4417]: [21772:4:0307/093535.316041:ERROR:persistent_asset_storage_impl.cc(113)] Initialize succeeded with already open DB
Mär 07 09:35:51 lin-messnere gnome-shell[1993]: libinput error: event9  - GXTP5100:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad: kernel bug: Touch jump detected and discarded.
Mär 07 09:35:51 lin-messnere gnome-shell[1993]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.20.0/touchpad-jumping-cursors.html for details
Mär 07 09:35:52 lin-messnere gnome-shell[1993]: libinput error: event9  - GXTP5100:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad: kernel bug: Touch jump detected and discarded.
Mär 07 09:35:52 lin-messnere gnome-shell[1993]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.20.0/touchpad-jumping-cursors.html for details
Mär 07 09:35:52 lin-messnere gnome-shell[1993]: libinput error: event9  - GXTP5100:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 43ms, your system is too slow
Mär 07 09:35:53 lin-messnere gnome-shell[1993]: libinput error: event9  - GXTP5100:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad: kernel bug: Touch jump detected and discarded.
Mär 07 09:35:53 lin-messnere gnome-shell[1993]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.20.0/touchpad-jumping-cursors.html for details
Mär 07 09:36:13 lin-messnere kernel: sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.
Mär 07 09:36:14 lin-messnere kernel: sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.
Mär 07 09:36:14 lin-messnere kernel: sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.
Mär 07 09:36:14 lin-messnere kernel: sysrq: Emergency Sync
```

My Ubuntu Version is 22.04.4 LTS.

My system specifications:

```
Hardware Model: Lenovo ThinkPad L14 Gen 3
Memory: 16,0 GiB
Processor: 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1235U × 12
Graphics: Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)
Disk Capacity: 512,1 GB
OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME Version: 42.9
Windowing System: Wayland
```

Can someone tell me what might be going on, or point me in the right direction? Could it be because of the RAM? Thanks!

Comment: This is usually a case of the system going out-of-memory, and everything getting stuck till the kernel figures out what to kill to make space for things to run again (in-kernel code that's called the OOM Killer). Enable a memory limit status widget to track memory usage. Also enable suspending and killing of inactive tabs in your browser settings. Lastly see if there are any services that you never end up using, and disable them if possible.

Comment: You could check the vm flags, as Ubuntu newer Kernel seems having a bugs regarding kswapd0, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/259739/kswapd0-is-taking-a-lot-of-cpu/530661#530661