"Permission denied" even when trying to open file (/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches) as root
When I do cat /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches as root (sudo bash) I get this error:
cat: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied

So how do I see the contents of that file?
()kswapd0 is running at 50% CPU and I was trying the suggestion at https://askubuntu.com/a/736956/180177 which involves messing with that file_)

On my (24.04) system it looks like the pseudofile has w but not r permission (perhaps this is a kernel 6.x thing?). Technically, you don't need to read the contents in order to implement the linked solution - only to write a new value.

@steeldriver s observation agrees with mine.  It's write only for root on my 24.04 system.  It's the same on my 22.04 system as well.

... in fact when you think about it, it doesn't make sense to read a value - since the values written to this particular pseudofile don't persist (they're just one-time instructions)
