# How can I enable the "magic sysrq key" on ubuntu desktop?

Tags: sysrq

The magic <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key does not work on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I imagine it's now disabled by default. My attempts to enable it did not work, and the only thing Google finds is a 2007 forum post from when it was apparently enabled by default.

Can I enable it? If so, how?

[Added the following after the first answer:]

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key "In Ubuntu the combination of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd> acts as "print screen" command." This is in fact the behaviour I observe on a non-hung system, even after doing `sudo sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=1` I get some kind of screen capture on my desktop. Not what I want.

It's not practical to write to `/proc/sysrq-trigger` from a system that's basically hung, trying to get information to debug the problem.

Comment: Looks like a dup to me too, or more correctly it looks like the answers also answer my question, which is not really the same - I'm not just interested in one specific non-working sysrq option.   I'll try the suggestions there, and see whether they still work; it's possible that additional changes to Ubuntu have made them out of date. (The question dates to 2013.)

Answer (score 25):

To enable sysrq magic keys temporarily:

`# echo "1" > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`

or `# sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=1`

This enables sysrq magic keys for the current user session. You can disable it again by exchanging 1 with 0 in the above commands. Or go back to the standard value of **176**.

To enable these changes at boot time one has to create config file in the sysctl.d directory (e.g. /etc/sysctl.d/90-sysrq.conf) with this line:

```
kernel.sysrq=1
```

So setting /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq to **1** enables the sysrq magic keys, setting it to **0** disables it.

Comment: I tried that.  Unfortunately this is ubuntu. Quoting wikipedia " In Ubuntu the combination of Alt+SysRequest acts as "print screen" command." And that's what I got

Comment: Well, sorry about that. I'm using KDE Neon, which is based on Ubuntu 16.04, and it worked for me.

Comment: Unity strikes again :-(

Comment: @ArlieStephens no you can, just edit /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf to change at the value you wish. Read more carefully wikipedia ;-)

Comment: Still doesn't work, even after `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` and `/etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf` are both set to '1'

Comment: @ArlieStephens: to workaround the "print screen" aspect: keep pressing `Alt` key, release `SysRq` key, press command key (e.g., `f` key to kill a memory hog https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html ). To test it, try `Alt+SysRq+h` and see the help message in `dmesg|tail`.

Comment: Sudo version: `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`