# Keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Alt + PrtScn + o doesn't work on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, 21.10

The keyboard shortcut  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> worked on Ubuntu 20.04, but it doesn't work with my current installation of Ubuntu 21.10, gnome: 40.4. This keyboard shortcut should shut down the computer instead of pressing the hardware power button for 4 seconds if necessary.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: Teh shortcut should shut down the computer instead of pressing 4 sec the hardware power button, if neccessary.

Comment: Does it answer your question https://askubuntu.com/questions/911522/how-can-i-enable-the-magic-sysrq-key-on-ubuntu-desktop ?

Answer (score 0):

your link helped me for the current session:
{{{
sudo sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=1
}}}
But I would prefer to have the possibilty after every boot.

If I try
{{{
sudo vi /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
}}}
there is only one line with the entry "16". I diddn't manage it to save it with value "1":
{{{
"/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq" E667: Fsync fehlgeschlagen
Betätigen Sie die EINGABETASTE oder geben Sie einen Befehl ein
}}}
I can't save it.

Nevertheless, I wonder why this option has been intentionally changed?