# CPU overheating when using SSD in DVD bay with a caddy, kworker using 20%cpu

Tags: ssd, ubuntu-gnome, overheating, cpu-load

I am using a dell laptop, CPU i7, GPU NVIDIA, RAM 8GB.

I bought an ssd and put it in a caddy and put in the dvd bay. Then I installed ubuntu-gnome 16.04 onto this ssd. This ssd is the second drive on the system, the primary hdd is still there.

I can see that there is a kworker process which is consistently using 20% of cpu even when system is idle. Normally system uses only 1% of cpu when idle.

Searching internet for this issue, I found this thread [Kworker, what is it and why is it hogging so much CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu)  which suggests to do

```
echo 1 > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

and then check

```
dmesg
```

where I can see the following..

```
[   19.363697] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   25.172294] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
```

Interestingly, the system is able to boot from the ssd and in general is working fine other than the kworker hogging cpu and heating much more (~70°C) than normal (~40°C).

So, how do I configure the system to use the ssd properly? I do not want my poor cpu to be overworking all the time and heating up.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. I can provide any info/logs that you guys require.

Comment: Whether it's a SSD or HDD or whatever, in a caddy or anywhere else, has nothing to do with "overheating" or CPU hogs. Most of your question is just "noise". Here's what I think is the main factor: Not using the proprietary Nvidia drivers. PS - 70C is warmer than the usual idle temps but it's perfectly within the acceptable range.

Comment: Thanks Michael for taking time to write this. However, I _am_ using proprietary nvidia driver ('additional drivers' in 'software and update').

Also, the heating/hogging issue does not occur when I remove the ssd and boot from the fixed hdd.

Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: Do you have a swap partition in use for the SSD?

Answer (score 1):

Please read this article. [Load average is high after adding second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149647/load-average-is-high-after-adding-second-drive)

I solved my problem just by switching the button (like this on the pic)