# Kworker Overload

Tags: kernel, mouse, suspend

Whenever I wake my computer from a "Suspend", System Monitor shows over 80 instances of kworker spontaneously get spawned.  If I then move the mouse, the PC crashes and I must restart.

If I don't touch the mouse and let the PC sit untouched for about 10 minutes, the 80 extra kworker daemons terminate and only the "normal" 8 remain.  The PC operates fine from then on.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04LTS.  It would be nice if kworker behaved.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is reproducible in a Virtual Machine or other hardware, then please file a bug report. If this reproducible *only* on your current hardware, then there's not much we can do.

Comment: Which kernel version are you running? 
Do you use btrfs?

Comment: Problem is reproducible on two other machines, one running Ubuntu 15.04, kernel=3.19.0-21-generic.  The other two (16.04) use kernel 4.4.0.116-generic.  Will investigate how to file a bug report, but anyone can try this at home:  Before you quit work for the day, launch System Monitor, check "All Processes", then search for kworker to see how many instances are running.  Then click Suspend to turn the computer off.  Next day, wake the computer by hitting the Ctrl button.  System Monitor window will fill with kworker entries after a second or two.  pim, none of my PC's use btrfs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kworker, what is it and why is it hogging so much CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu)