# Single CPU core 100% full all the time on Ubuntu

Tags: cpu, process

There are some days since when I noted a single CPU core of my system is working basically at 100% of its capacity all the time on Ubuntu (first at 18.04, but I updated to 20.04 LTS and the problem persisted). I inspected the system with htop and disabled some processes I suspected were causing the problem (like a task called '*baloo_file*'), but it didn't work. I also tried unsuccessfully some things which are described [here](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-single-cpu-always-at-100-lagging-ubuntu-18-04-4/), like to install a different desktop manager (gdm3 instead of lightdm) and to install a different desktop environment (lubuntu).

I think it's being caused by some mysterious process on the system, but I have no idea which one. And I'm confident it is only on Ubuntu, since I checked it on Windows, and there things are fine. Ideas?

Here are some printscreens of htop and system's monitor to serve as evidence of the problem:

[image: Text]

[image: System's Monitor]

Comment: Sure! Updated it.

Comment: I was hoping it might be more revealing, but I don't notice anything to explain the 100% on the 4th core.  Is this behavior associated with a specific application?

Comment: `apt install dstat` then `dstat -v --top-cpu`. The last column will tell you the "most expensive" process. Leave it running for a minute, then paste the result.

Comment: Ok, so doing that I see lots of `kworker/0:1+u 19` or similar stuff on the last column. Probably we've found the culprit

Comment: So, I did exactly what is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044872/ubuntu-16-04-kworker-using-high-cpu-constantly) and my busy CPU core now seems to be free :)