# How to interpret perf report

Tags: performance

My laptop is hot and the fan is always running. First I ensured the discreet graphics card is disabled (it is), then I checked the system monitor and `top`:

[image: System Monitor]

[image: Top]

Looks like a mystery `kworker` task is hogging nearly all of one cpu. I installed `perf` and ran the commands `sudo perf record -g -a sleep 10` & `sudo perf report` to get this:

[image: Perf output]

Now what? I'm really not sure what any of these processes are. Any tips?

Comment: Do you have 8 kernels? The `kworker` process appears 65% busy, yet your system as a whole is only 9% busy.

Comment: It's a Quad Core i7-3615QM - maybe each of the 4 CPUs is dual because the System Monitor reports activity for 8 CPUs.

Comment: OK, that part makes sense then.

Comment: Hey @coleman! This Q&A on `kworker` might be of some help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu ... maybe that's how you were led to using `perf`, but there are some steps to keep debugging over on that Q anyway!

Comment: Is there anything repeatedly logged to syslog?