# Hard drive constantly accessing

Tags: hard-drive, kubuntu, 19.04

I'm using Kubuntu 19.04. My hard drive is being constantly accessed by the following to processes.

[kworker/u32:2-events_freezable_power_]

[kworker/u32:2-edac-poller]

Can I stop these two processes and how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kworker, what is it and why is it hogging so much CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the linked question, informative as it is, will not contribute providing a solution. I had issues with kworker/0:3+kacpid and kworker/0:3+kacpi-notify and I could resolve this by adding usbcore.autosuspend=-1 to the kernel's boot command line in /etc/default/grub. In your case, something else may be the issue, though.