# Hard disk red LED constantly turned on

Tags: kernel, hard-drive, performance, 20.04

With ubuntu installed on my PC, the hard disk red LED is constantly on, it gets turned off for a couple of seconds but then goes on again for a longer time. During this time, the system is basically in idle state (not doing anything special).

I referred to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/422151 to install perf and here are the result:

```
+   27,70%     0,00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] secondary_startup_64
+   27,70%     0,00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] cpu_startup_entry
+   27,65%     0,04%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] do_idle
+   26,09%     0,02%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] call_cpuidle
+   26,06%     0,00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] cpuidle_enter
+   26,04%     0,07%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] cpuidle_enter_state
+   24,89%     0,00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] start_secondary
+   24,45%    24,37%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] intel_idle
+    5,93%     0,00%  gnome-shell      [unknown]                        [.] 0000000000000000
+    3,03%     0,00%  Xorg             [unknown]                        [k] 0000000000000000
+    2,96%     0,08%  Xorg             [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
+    2,84%     0,51%  Xorg             [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] do_syscall_64
+    2,81%     0,00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] x86_64_start_kernel
+    2,81%     0,00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] x86_64_start_reservations
+    2,81%     0,00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] start_kernel
+    2,81%     0,00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] arch_call_rest_init
+    2,81%     0,00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                [k] rest_init
+    2,76%     0,04%  chrome           chrome                           [.] free
```

i still don't get what is causing this problem.

Could somebody give some hints on how to debug and fix this?

**update:**

the output of free -m

```
➜ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15932        5797        7010         639        3124        9168
Swap:          2047        1456         591
```

the output of the `/proc/meminfo` is:

```
MemTotal:       16314684 kB
MemFree:         7078640 kB
MemAvailable:    9293936 kB
Buffers:          183180 kB
Cached:          2849624 kB
SwapCached:       163900 kB
Active:          5521352 kB
Inactive:        3009000 kB
Active(anon):    4687400 kB
Inactive(anon):  1461260 kB
Active(file):     833952 kB
Inactive(file):  1547740 kB
Unevictable:          64 kB
Mlocked:              64 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:         607576 kB
Dirty:             21520 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       5334264 kB
Mapped:          1207368 kB
Shmem:            654420 kB
KReclaimable:     171680 kB
Slab:             417120 kB
SReclaimable:     171680 kB
SUnreclaim:       245440 kB
KernelStack:       23328 kB
PageTables:        67608 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    10254488 kB
Committed_AS:   19727368 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       59852 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             7392 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      536284 kB
DirectMap2M:     7770112 kB
DirectMap1G:    10485760 kB
```

and here is the output for:

```
root@servlus:/home/serv/~# iotop -o -b | grep -i kworker
  13830 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.30 % [kworker/u16:3-events_power_efficient]
  30898 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.22 % [kworker/u16:2-events_freezable_power_]
  21605 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.15 % [kworker/u16:1-events_freezable_power_]
  32089 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.07 % [kworker/u16:6-events_freezable_power_]
  30898 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/u16:2-events_power_efficient]
  13830 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.29 % [kworker/u16:3-events_unbound]
  21605 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.22 % [kworker/u16:1-events_power_efficient]
  32089 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.15 % [kworker/u16:6-events_freezable_power_]
  30898 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.08 % [kworker/u16:2-events_freezable_power_]
  13830 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/u16:3-events_freezable_power_]
  13830 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.23 % [kworker/u16:3-events_unbound]
  21605 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.22 % [kworker/u16:1-events_power_efficient]
  30898 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.29 % [kworker/u16:2-events_power_efficient]
  13830 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.22 % [kworker/u16:3-events_freezable_power_]
  32089 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.15 % [kworker/u16:6-events_freezable_power_]
  21605 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.07 % [kworker/u16:1-events_freezable_power_]
  30898 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/u16:2-events_power_efficient]
  13830 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.30 % [kworker/u16:3-events_power_efficient]
  32089 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.23 % [kworker/u16:6-events_freezable_power_]
  21605 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.16 % [kworker/u16:1-events_freezable_power_]
  30898 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.08 % [kworker/u16:2-events_freezable_power_]
```

and here is output for `sysctl vm.swappiness`:

```
root@servlus:/home/serv/~# sysctl vm.swappiness

vm.swappiness = 60
```

output for `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`

```
root@servlus:/home/serv/~# grep -i swap /etc/fstab 
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

output for top:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                             
  16404 serv      20   0   18,9g 400084 122388 S  69,8   2,5  94:04.24 chrome                                                                                                              
  33283 root      20   0   35780  18768   7352 R  23,6   0,1   2:29.60 iotop                                                                                                               
   9275 serv      20   0  766204 367428 102656 S  22,6   2,3  32:53.18 chrome                                                                                                              
   2685 serv      20   0 4840508 223616  83896 R  20,9   1,4  30:58.12 gnome-shell                                                                                                         
   9279 serv      20   0  378864  57876  26924 S   8,3   0,4  11:27.19 chrome                                                                                                              
   2462 root      20   0  339976  72568  60504 S   8,0   0,4  11:40.55 Xorg                                                                                                                
   1803 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   6,3   0,0   8:55.88 irq/56-nvidia                                                                                                       
   9236 serv      20   0 1496608 283636 101768 S   3,7   1,7   8:07.33 chrome                                                                                                              
  14029 serv      20   0  909164  61992  40180 S   3,3   0,4   1:07.76 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                     
   2384 serv      20   0 3146556  10232   7456 S   2,7   0,1   4:12.82 pulseaudio                                                                                                          
  15548 serv      20   0  596624  48368  34760 S   2,7   0,3   2:10.61 gnome-disks                                                                                                         
   4118 serv      20   0 8220884   1,3g  20704 S   2,0   8,1  16:40.11 java                                                                                                                
   8666 serv      20   0 1201020  42848   6168 S   1,3   0,3   3:48.64 gulp watch                                                                                                          
   7898 serv      20   0 4671616   1,3g  63440 S   1,0   8,6   7:00.56 telegram-deskto                                                                                                     
    727 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,7   0,0   1:33.70 nvidia-modeset/                                                                                                     
   1387 root      20   0    2540      0      0 S   0,7   0,0   0:16.40 acpid                                                                                                               
  16517 serv      20   0  833012  62304  50708 S   0,7   0,4   1:09.02 chrome                                                                                                              
      1 root      20   0  169564   9516   4852 S   0,3   0,1   0:11.53 systemd                                                                                                             
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3   0,0   0:00.57 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                         
   1393 message+  20   0   10172   4456   2124 S   0,3   0,0   0:14.11 dbus-daemon                                                                                                         
   1423 root      20   0  253936   8472   4920 S   0,3   0,1   0:26.11 polkitd                                                                                                             
   1429 root      20   0   16948   2852   2508 S   0,3   0,0   0:06.74 systemd-logind                                                                                                      
   1431 root      20   0  822648  12328   5452 S   0,3   0,1   0:15.40 udisksd                                                                                                             
   1805 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3   0,0   0:06.25 nv_queue                                                                                                            
   2580 serv      20   0  397828   5724   3860 S   0,3   0,0   0:12.85 ibus-daemon                                                                                                         
   9401 serv      20   0   14,5g  80024  41064 S   0,3   0,5   0:30.50 chrome                                                                                                              
  10876 serv      20   0   23,2g 250692  65600 S   0,3   1,5   0:51.70 slack                                                                                                               
  20110 serv      20   0 4763912 167396  86664 S   0,3   1,0   1:55.58 chrome                                                                                                              
  33186 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:00.21 kworker/6:0-events                                                                                                  
  34619 root      20   0   20972   4244   3284 R   0,3   0,0   0:00.11 top
```

output for :

```
root@servlus:/home/serv/~# ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/root/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
root@servlus:/home/serv/~# ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 avril 23 09:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 avril 23 09:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 avril 23 09:35 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 avril 23 09:35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 avril 23 09:35 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

top from root:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                             
  36402 serv    20   0   18,8g 360672 119280 S  79,4   2,2   5:06.82 chrome                                                                                                              
  35817 serv    20   0  572632 288120 134216 S  23,3   1,8   2:15.15 chrome                                                                                                              
   2685 serv    20   0 4850620 234440  83980 S  20,9   1,4  34:00.83 gnome-shell                                                                                                         
  35820 serv    20   0  359148  87784  67416 S   9,6   0,5   0:38.56 chrome                                                                                                              
   2462 root      20   0  335368  74732  62640 S   7,0   0,5  12:40.14 Xorg                                                                                                                
   1803 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   6,3   0,0   9:42.38 irq/56-nvidia                                                                                                       
  35781 serv    20   0  886848 243528 133180 S   3,3   1,5   0:43.22 chrome                                                                                                              
   2384 serv    20   0 2687792  10020   7244 S   3,0   0,1   4:35.63 pulseaudio                                                                                                          
  14029 serv    20   0  909224  62204  40432 S   2,3   0,4   1:15.19 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                     
   4118 serv    20   0 8220884   1,3g  20704 S   2,0   8,1  17:04.28 java                                                                                                                
   8666 serv    20   0 1201020  42848   6168 S   1,7   0,3   4:04.97 gulp watch                                                                                                          
   7898 serv    20   0 4671616   1,3g  63568 S   1,3   8,6   7:12.28 telegram-deskto                                                                                                     
   1387 root      20   0    2540      0      0 S   1,0   0,0   0:19.16 acpid                                                                                                               
    727 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,7   0,0   1:40.64 nvidia-modeset/                                                                                                     
  36487 serv    20   0  824816  61368  49868 S   0,7   0,4   0:03.52 chrome                                                                                                              
      1 root      20   0  169564   9516   4852 S   0,3   0,1   0:12.70 systemd                                                                                                             
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:15.38 rcu_sched                                                                                                           
    354 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3   0,0   0:02.53 jbd2/sda2-8                                                                                                         
   1684 root      20   0 1363284    412      0 S   0,3   0,0   0:15.74 teamviewerd                                                                                                         
  10876 serv    20   0   23,1g 250020  65600 S   0,3   1,5   0:54.34 slack                                                                                                               
  30898 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:00.17 kworker/u16:2-events_power_efficient                                                                                
  35942 serv    20   0 4601424  83936  63396 S   0,3   0,5   0:00.57 chrome                                                                                                              
  36457 serv    20   0 4696756 131380  81088 S   0,3   0,8   0:02.60 chrome                                                                                                              
  37788 root      20   0   20972   4368   3408 R   0,3   0,0   0:00.06 top
```

output for top from root after killing chrome

https://pastebin.com/raw/HRCHqqf2

Comment: Looks like swap usage. Have you checked the output of `free -m`?

Comment: @mikewhatever i updated the question with the output of the command

Comment: So, yes, that was swap usage. What programs were running at the time it happened?

Comment: Show me `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `top`.

Comment: @heynnema ```root@servlus:/home/serv/~# sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60```

Comment: Good. And the other commands?

Comment: @heynnema i updated the post with the outputs you asked for

Comment: Kill `chrome` and see if it stops swapping, and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema updated it

Comment: That was done from root. Do you normally log into serv? Your top command doesn't look current, is it?

Comment: i am always in serv, i switched to root temporarily to run some commands, and my terminal just stood there... :facepalm: 
should i repeat them in serv? @heynnema

Comment: If `top` looks the same as what's in your question, did you kill `chrome` and see if the swapping stopped?

Comment: @heynnema i shared another output for top from root

Comment: Oh, sorry. You just `su` -d to get to root. It still shows `chrome`... and a bunch of other apps... telegram, etc.

Comment: @heynnema i shared the output for root after killing chrome https://pastebin.com/raw/HRCHqqf2

Comment: Did the swapping stop?

Comment: @heynnema sorry, i am not linux techie, how do i know if it stopped or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107477/discussion-between-heynnema-and-teebeetee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the number/kind of apps you normally run, your current 2G /swapfile is getting eaten alive.

Assure that there's not one particular app that's eating swap, by using the `free -h` command, and watching `swap used`. Chrome, a thousand open tabs, and it's add-ons, are known memory eaters.

We'll enlarge the /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: i ran all these commands, and now i have 4G of swap... I will keep an eye on it and see what happens during the day...

Comment: @teebeetee keep me posted. Start comments to me with "@heynnema" or I'll surely miss them.