# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS CPU1 always at 80% no matter what

Tags: 20.04, lts, cpu-load, surface

I'm a completely new user. I installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my Surface Book 2 and I've been having a couple of problems.
The most annoying one is that it is extremely slow. CPU 1 is AT LEAST at 80% usage at all times. [System monitor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8jxg.png)

I've tried to identify the problem looking up other questions but I can't solve it.

`grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts` yields no unusually high values (the Max value is 43).

kworker/0:2+kacpi_notify is the top process at 85%~ kworker/u16:0+kacpi_hotplug is the second at 20%~

How else can I go about this?

Here's a screenshot of my other specs if it helps. [Specs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SsA6.png)

Comment: Weren't you able to find out which process is using the CPU? You can go to the System Monitor's **Process** tab and sort by **% CPU** column or use the `top` command from a terminal.

Comment: Yes! kworker/0:2+kacpi_notify is the top process at 85%~ kworker/u16:0+kacpi_hotplug is the second at 20%~.  Not sure if I can kill these processes?

Comment: You can [edit] and change your question to mention these processes. You can look also at this old question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/

Comment: Ok what I got from that question is that I should basically update my kernel until the problem is gone. I updated to kernel 5.9.1 and now it's even worse :(