# KDE-related processes

Tags: kde, process, monitoring, system-monitor

**Important:** I used to have the KDE Plasma DE installed but I removed that months ago.

I checked activity monitor like I do a lot, and I decided to check the "all processes" button instead of just the "my processes." Now I see a lot of KDE-related processes like things starting with `kworker`, and other things that start with "k," which is what most KDE things start with. (I also see lots of other processes like `loop32` but those have nothing to do with this question.)

First, are these KDE processes that I don't need? Secondly, if they are, how do I get rid of them? There are so many processes that start with "kworker" and just overall the letter "k."

Here is a list of some of the things I'm seeing: `kworker`*, `kblockd`, `ksoftrqd`*, `kthreadd`, `krcommd`, `kintegrityd`, `kswapd0`. These are **not all** of them, this is just a sample.

Also, here's a picture of what I'm seeing as well (picture mainly focused on `kworker`):

[image]

First, are these KDE processes that I don't need, and are from KDE Plasma? What are these processes? Secondly, if they are what I think they are, how do I get rid of them? There are so many processes that start with "kworker" and just overall the letter "k." The only app I can think of that is developed by KDE that I've installed is Kdenlive, but that's an AppImage.

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `kworker` for one means *kernel worker* and relates to threads on your system, and **not** KDE.  Don't forget K from Kernel and K from KDE share the same letter  (ie. if you want to complain about KDE processes you should be ignoring kernel processes which relate to the Linux Kernel; and I've yet to recognize a single KDE thread in your post)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kworker, what is it and why is it hogging so much CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu)