# After installation - Interrupts - kworker/dependencies CPU core overload

Tags: system-installation, interrupts

I have close to 100 interrupts. I'm afraid to spread error code online, the computer is an HP Pavilion 690 0024 np Intel i5 the motherboard is Unix. I have insufficient knowledge to fix this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not know what the problem is you want help with. Your pictures look normal. I have 138 files in `/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts` and 54 kworker threads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kworker, what is it and why is it hogging so much CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu)