# KWORKER is hogging the processor

Tags: kernel, performance

My plex server on Ubuntu server 22.04.2 was buffering too much so I checked my processes with the `top` command and it showed this.

I don't know what it is. Can I stop it? It's using 20% of my CPU.

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   5751 root      20   0       0      0      0 I  20.9   0.0   3:47.05 kworker/1:3-events
```

Comment: The Plex Media Server can use up quite a bit of CPU and GPU while playing movies or TV shows.  Basically anything that needs transcoding can do it.  Mine can go anywhere from 2% to 30%.

Comment: @Terrance haha when my CPU is transcoding it goes to 98% it makes me worried cause the fan speeds don't change but I am working on it. i was wondering if you can tell me how can I set my plex server so that It uses my 2Gb and GPU for transcoding. Will it help? thanks already

Comment: Better transcoding comes from a better video card that supports it.  Also, more RAM would help the system out a lot.  You might want to read through https://support.plex.tv/articles/115002178853-using-hardware-accelerated-streaming/

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu#421916 on how to debug this

Comment: nice and renice commands might help tame it, I have had to do that to recollindex.